# How can I do oracle regexp_substr in mongo

Tags: mongodb, database

In oracle:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('a b c d', '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 1) FROM dual;
```

Will output 'a' by this sql.

Can mongo db do this too?

I can't find the way.